# Standard way to make a CSV file for classification with n-grams

Tags: python, csv, nlp, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I want to make a CSV file from n-grams of the tweets with 0/1 labels for binary classification. What is the best and standard structure of the CSV file to do that?

Do you agree with the below example structure?

```
pos_tweet = 'I love you'
neg_tweet = 'I hate you'
```

CSV file:

```
bigram, label
I love, 1
love you, 1
I hate, 0
hate you, 0
```

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to do this, but the approach you propose looks perfectly workable.

Comment: @maarten I'm not sure, but I think since grams belong to the same tweet, they should not be written in different rows. Don't you think?

Comment: It all depends on the type of analysis you want to do on it. If your goal is to give a single positive/negative classification of a tweet than you could take the n-gram classification approach and do a majority vote using all n-grams in the tweet. If your goal is to take a more advanced approach, then you may want to keep the tweet ID, and the order of the n-grams in the tweet as well.

Comment: @ECubDevs Don't multiply your data. You have 2 entries. Tokenize them with any tokenization scheme that suits you (2-3-n gram, n-chars whatever) and write them as a comma separated list or matrix if you wish (BOW). You may also check `sklearn`, where you'll find alll the answers you need